# Is the Protection fighting style considered subpar?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighting-style

I do not see Protection recommended in many places. It seems like it might be considered in the community to not be as good as other options. Is it actually subpar, and if so, why? Is disadvantage on an attack not good?

Comment: Please add additional details about the phenomenon that you want us to investigate. I voted to leave closed -from review.

Comment: If you're going to self-answer, you can do a much better job of asking the question.

Comment: @T.J.L. I hoped so too, but it is much harder than I thought.

Comment: It seems you are making the question just so you can include the answer, and the question is quite poor at the moment. It's like "I heard something, why is it true?" - but without even referencing, e.g., where you heard that.

Comment: I'll note that András is not referenceing something they have seen, but the absence of it (i.e. people just don't appear to be recommending Protection).

Comment: I've revised this to not approach this as though Protection is already assumed to be bad, and instead to just ask about whether it is bad and why. ("Why is it considered subpar?" --> "Is it considered subpar?" among other changes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It is far from strong, and *feels* even weaker

It is great when it works, but cannot always be used, does not do anything half the time, and costs your reaction *even when it did nothing*.

### Limitations

- **Positioning:** Protection can only work if you have an adjacent ally, while Dueling or Defense does not need cooperation from your allies
- **Cost:** You have to spend your reaction to use it
- **Rare success:** More than half the time you won't see any effect (see below)

### Disappointment

Why would you feel disappointed? Let's go through all the possible rolls (assume the DM usually uses the red d20, the green only comes out for Advantage / Disadvantage)

- Both rolls high; the target is still hit, *disappointing*
- Both rolls low; it would not have hit anyway, *disappointing*
- Red low, green high; the disadvantage did not matter, the usual die would not have hit anyway, *disappointing*
- Red high, green low; you actually helped the ally! But look, the next attack you could have prevented is a natural 20, you should have used it on that one, *disappointing*

Obviously the last one does not happen this way every time. Still, even if you succeed, each time an enemy rolls higher later in the round, you *will* feel regret not preventing *that one* instead.

## Calculation

I will assume the enemy has 55% hit chance against the protected ally, 45% against you (you must have a shield for Protection), and compare using Protection on your ally, or Defense on yourself.

### Protection

If the enemy has 55% hit chance before disadvantage, it goes down to 30.25% (0.55 * 0.55), 24.75% gain.

### Defense

This decreases the enemy's hit chance from 45% to 40%, a 5% gain.

### Comparison

Protection can only be used once per round, so if you are attacked 5 times in a round, Defense is better. If you consider that Protection needs careful positioning and will not be usable every round, they prevent about equal amount of damage to the party per encounter<sup>1</sup>.

**The benefits are equal, but not the costs.** Defense is always on, but Protection consumes your reaction, preventing better uses of it<sup>2</sup>.

---

1. Preventing 10 damage to the Wizard is more useful than to the Fighter, compared to their max HP. However, at least in my experience, the front liners run out of Hit Dice well before the back row casters, meaning it is actually *better* to spread out the damage.
2. Opportunity attacks, Riposte (BM maneuver), Sentinel (feat), Counterspell (spell) etc.

Comment: The comparison between defense and protection is quite unfair. If you are using protection on someone, that someone is most likely more dependent on not being damaged than you are. So, damage done to that character is more harmful than damage done to yourself. I think the major problem is actually related to the positioning. If you could use it at range to help your squishy backlines it would improve *considerably*. Think Cutting Words.

Comment: @HellSaint, all of this is addressed in the answer.